# Showing Div Boxes with content when clicking on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a portfolio website and on my homepage I am trying to set it up where you click on navigation links and content boxes appear. My CSS for my div boxes work, and I am able to hide them with JQuery.  The problem is the boxes don't appear when I click on the link.  I'm thinking it has something to do with my link href attributes, but I'm not sure.  I included the portions of my code that have to do with this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id = "HomeNav">
    <div id ="Navabsolute">
        <ul>
            <li><a id = "skills" href= "#Skills" style=padding-right:190px;><img src="~/Content/Images/snowflake.png" style=width:91px;height:91px;vertical-align:middle;>Skills</a></li>
            <li><a id = "works" href= "#Resume" style=padding-right:190px;><img src="~/Content/Images/snowflake.png" style=width:91px;height:91px;vertical-align:middle;>Resume</a></li>
            <li><a id = "education" href= "#Education"><img src="~/Content/Images/snowflake.png" style=width:91px;height:91px;vertical-align:middle;>Work and Education</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="Skills"></div>
<div id="Resume"></div>
<div id="Education"></div
```

Javascript/JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Skills").hide();
    $("#Resume").hide();
    $("#Education").hide();

    $("#skills").click(function(){
        $("#Skills").show();
        $("#Resume").hide();
        $("#Education").hide();
    });

    $("#works").click(function(){
        $("#Skills").hide();
        $("#Resume").show();
        $("#Education").hide();
    });

    $("#education").click(function(){
        $("#Skills").hide();
        $("#Resume").hide();
        $("#Education").show();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#HomeNav {
     position: relative;
     width: 1200px;
     height: 750px;


}
#Navabsolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left:110px;
}

#Skills {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}

#Resume {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#Education {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Was the missing `>` on the end of `<div id="Education"></div` missing in your real code? If you add that in then it all seems to work fine. By the way, I know element `id` is supposed to be case sensitive, but it is pretty confusing reading code that uses `id` attributes that are identical other than the case of the first letter.

Comment: @nnnnnn -- Apparently it's [**illegal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Case_Sensitivity_in_class_and_id_Names) to use case-insensitive duplicate IDS -- "There is a further restriction, however, on the use of id names. Section 12.2.1 makes it illegal for the name and id attributes to use values which are a case-insensitive match". The article is obsolete though, so not sure if this is still the case?

Comment: @ObsidianAge - Well it may be illegal but work anyway in some browsers, I don't know. The OP's code worked for me once I fixed the missing `>` at the end of the HTML, so I guess the IDs did work in Chrome. Either way it makes the code hard to read.

Comment: I didn't have the missing > at the end of the div tag for my education content box, so that wasn't causing the problem for me anyway.  I did go head and change the id values of my links to avoid the case sensitivity and the naming confusion.  That still didn't fix the issue for me.

Comment: So I am coding this in visual studio using ASP.NET MVC and can't get it to work.  It will work just fine with a regular text editor, but for some reason the jquery code won't work in visual studio.  I have no idea why that is.  The div boxes hide just fine, but they won't appear in visual studio like they would in another text editor.  Its pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

Hi looks like your id for div box is a bit confused. I have changed your div id and run Jquery it looks work to me. 
just have look at following code it may help.

< div id="a"> skills </div>

< div id="b"> works </div>

< div id="c"> education </div>

```
<code><script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#a").hide();
          $("#b").hide();
          $("#c").hide();

    $("#skills").click(function(){
            $("#a").show();
            $("#b").hide();
            $("#c").hide();
        });

    $("#works").click(function(){
            $("#a").hide();
            $("#b").show();
            $("#c").hide();
        });

        $("#education").click(function(){
            $("#a").hide();
            $("#b").hide();
            $("#c").show();
        });
    });
</script></code>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I tried it in a regular text editor as well and it works like a charm.  The problem is I'm actually working with this in Visual Studio with ASP.NET MVC and its not working.  I have no clue what is going on there.  Is there a right way to get jquery to fully run properly with ASP.NET?